# Foreman start returns bundle not found

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, bundler, foreman

I have recently switched from using Ubuntu system Ruby to using RVM. When I run `foreman start` I get a not found error for whatever the command is in my Procfile.

My current Procfile is:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./unicorn.rb
```

So the error is:

```
/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/foreman-0.60.2/bin/foreman-runner: 41: exec: bundle: not found
```

`which foreman` returns

```
/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/foreman
```

`which bundle` returns

```
/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/bundle
```

The output from `rvm info` is:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p327:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-19-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 13 17:48:01 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.10/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.17.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "1 hour 10 minutes 26 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p327"
    date:         "2012-11-10"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-11-10 revision 37606"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327"
    ruby:         "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/home/timmillwood/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/home/timmillwood/Support-Tools/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327"
    GEM_PATH:     "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327:/home/timmillwood/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327"
    IRBRC:        "/home/timmillwood/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

I have also tried using rbenv with exactly the same issues. Foreman worked fine which I was using the system ruby, but I have purged these from Ubuntu and want to use RVM or rbenv so I can run Ruby 1.9 and 1.8.

It's as if foreman can't find the bundle binary. I can run `bundle exec ruby web.rb` or `ruby web.rb` to run a sinatra app, but that fails because it's not loading my environment variables from .env like foreman does. I could use rack-env to load my .env file, then load my sinatra app using `ruby web.rb` but would rather use foreman.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Are you doing 'bundle exec foreman start'?

Comment: No I'm not, and if I try that it gives exactly the same result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Turns out I had `PATH` overridden in my .env file I generated via `heroku config:pull`. Deleting that line has solved the problem.

Thanks all, nothing to see here.

Answer (score 0):

seams like your `~/.profile` could overwrite `PATH` -> https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/blob/master/bin/foreman-runner#L37, make sure there is no `PATH=...` in `~/.profile` or any other file loaded with it.

Comment: I did have: `export PATH="/home/timmillwood/perl5/bin:$PATH";` and `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting` in my .bashrc, but after removing these and restarting my terminal I still have the same issue.

Comment: There are a few `PATH=...` but commenting them out doesn't help, and they all add to rather than replace PATH, but having `$PATH` at the start or end.